# Изменить цвет у Border

Tags: java, swing

Есть `Border`:

`Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);`

Этот бордер я устанавливаю для элемента `JLabel`

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на мой `JLabel` менялся цвет этой рамки. Проблема в том, что у рамки нет методов вроде `setColor()` и т.д. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Добавляю пример кода:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
Click click = new Click();
public Window() {
    JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[9];
    for(JLabel label : labels) {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.addMouseListener(click);
        add(label);
    }
}

class Click extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (Jlabel)e.getComponent();//На всякий случай можно получить элемент по которому кликнули...
        border.//??? Тут нужно поменять цвет на красный
    }
}
}
```

Comment: приведите хоть немного кода, что ли..

Comment: JLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED)); создайте новый Border с новым цветом и присвойте его  JLabel. А вообще переходите на JavaFX. Swing уже давно устарел

Comment: @boneferz, Вы присваиваете новый бордер элементу JLabel, а мне нужно именно изменить цвет у существующего, так как у меня один бордер используется на несколько JLabel'ов одновременно. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: не уверен, но попробуйте setForeground

Comment: @boneferz, такого метода тоже нет. `Border` не наследник `Component`'a, как я понимаю.

Comment: @michael_best, добавил кусок кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

public TestFrame() throws HeadlessException {
    JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[9];
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Dimension maxSize = new Dimension(100,30);
    for(JLabel label : labels) {
        label = new JLabel("test");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(new MyBorder(Color.BLACK,2));
        label.addMouseListener(new Click());
        label.setMaximumSize(maxSize);
        getContentPane().add(label);
    }
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

class Click extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getComponent();//На всякий случай можно получить элемент по которому кликнули...
        ((MyBorder)label.getBorder()).changeColor(label,Color.RED);//??? Тут нужно поменять цвет на красный
    }
}

private class MyBorder extends LineBorder{

    private Color newColor;

    public MyBorder(Color color, int thickness) {
        super(color, thickness);
    }

    public void changeColor(JLabel label,Color color){
        lineColor = color;
        getGraphics().setColor(color);
        Point p = label.getLocationOnScreen();
        paintBorder(label,getGraphics(),p.x,p.y,label.getWidth(),label.getHeight());
    }
}
```

}